# Divide every element in a python nested array by an integer

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I have a large nested list in python, with some of the elements in the list being numpy arrays. Its structure is as follows:

```
listExample[x][y][z] = an integer
listExample[x][y] = a numpy array
```

There are many combinations of x, y, and z. I'd like to divide all the integers in the list array (all of which are in `list[x][y][z]`) by 100.

**Example structure of list/array:**

```
listExample[
 [
  [ [100, 200, 300], [230, 133, 234] ],
  [ [234, 232, 523], [231, 234, 554] ]
 ],
 [
  [ [701, 704, 204], [331, 833, 634] ],
  [ [734, 632, 523], [131, 434, 154] ]
 ] 
]
```

**I am trying to generate an output like this for the above example of the list:**

```
listExample[
 [
  [ [1, 2, 3], [2.3, 1.33, 2.34] ],
  [ [2.34, 2.32, 5.23], [2.31, 2.34, 5.54] ]
 ],
 [
  [ [7.01, 7.04, 2.04], [3.31, 8.33, 6.34] ],
  [ [7.34, 6.32, 5.23], [1.31, 4.34, 1.54] ]
 ] 
]
```

*I have used indentations in the above example input and output to make it easier to read a multidimensional array.*

Other questions on StackOverflow divide lists by integers using numpy or something like this:

```
listExample = [i/100 for i in listExample]
```

This doesn't work, however, as this is a nested array. It will spit out this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

**So, how am I supposed to divide every integer in my array/list by 100?**

Comment: now is it using `numpy` or `list` ? [mcve] please

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's a list with numpy arrays within it as elements. Each element in list[x][y] is a numpy array with z elements.

Comment: a sample of the input data & expected output would be a great help

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yep, done.

Comment: Your example is a list of list of list, not a list of list of `np.array`

Comment: @Scott The example is to describe the structure and nesting of the list/array. It doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

IF you are open to using a 3rd party library, you can use `numpy` for a vectorised solution:

**Setup**

```
import numpy as np

lst = [
 [
  [ [100, 200, 300], [230, 133, 234] ],
  [ [234, 232, 523], [231, 234, 554] ]
 ],
 [
  [ [701, 704, 204], [331, 833, 634] ],
  [ [734, 632, 523], [131, 434, 154] ]
 ] 
]
```

**Solution**

```
res = np.array(lst)/100

array([[[[ 1.  ,  2.  ,  3.  ],
         [ 2.3 ,  1.33,  2.34]],

        [[ 2.34,  2.32,  5.23],
         [ 2.31,  2.34,  5.54]]],


       [[[ 7.01,  7.04,  2.04],
         [ 3.31,  8.33,  6.34]],

        [[ 7.34,  6.32,  5.23],
         [ 1.31,  4.34,  1.54]]]])
```

Comment: I'm getting an error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'

Comment: @AdityaRadhakrishnan, See update. I cannot replicate your error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy's **divide** method:

```
import numpy as np 
arr1 = [
 [
  [ [100, 200, 300], [230, 133, 234] ],
  [ [234, 232, 523], [231, 234, 554] ]
 ],
 [
  [ [701, 704, 204], [331, 833, 634] ],
  [ [734, 632, 523], [131, 434, 154] ]
 ] 
]
out = np.divide(arr1, 100) 

print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[[[1.   2.   3.  ]
   [2.3  1.33 2.34]]

  [[2.34 2.32 5.23]
   [2.31 2.34 5.54]]]


 [[[7.01 7.04 2.04]
   [3.31 8.33 6.34]]

  [[7.34 6.32 5.23]
   [1.31 4.34 1.54]]]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Loop through the lists, and divide equals the `numpy` arrays.

```
loloa = [[np.array([1,2]), np.array([3,4])],[np.array([5,6])]]
for loa in loloa:
    for i in range(len(loa)):
        loa[i] = loa[i]/100
print(loloa)
```